# Find region of map containing point

Tags: geometry, maps

I have a region that's partitioned into a bunch of subregions called blocks. I have a graph that's encoded as follows: every block is given a node, and (i,j) is an edge iff blocks i and j touch. I have a (long, long) list of points, and for each point I want to find the block that contains that point. Is there a faster algorithm than just picking a random vertex on the graph and A* searching on Euclidean distance?

Comment: (long, long) list ? Do you mean very very long ?

Comment: A figure would be helpful. What's the shape of a block ? Have you considered the Voronoi diagram/post office search ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Start with a random block.
2. Determine if the block contains the point.
3. Determine wich of the neighbours blocks (you have neighbours through edges) has the shortest distance to target.
4. Move to that block.
5. Repeat steps 2-4 until step "2" is true.

Note that if you track the block you come from you don't need to test this block at step "3".